# For /f only shows first word

Tags: batch, batch-file

So i have a txt(infos.txt) and in Infos is an Sentence:

```
echo This is a Sentence!
echo This is a Sentence in the 2nd line!
```

and now i use

```
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (infos.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
echo %line%
```

to Show me the Sentence but its always only the First word.
It would be really nice if you could help me.
Thanks for Future answers.

Comment: Add `delims=` option and think about the `skip=1` one. https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: You could also try `for /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (infos.txt)`. The issue is that without specifying tokens "everything" or delims "nothing", then the default for a delimiter is a space and thus you get the first word for the first token per sentence since after that first word is a space and thus another token.

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks for The Comments!
I fixed it like this:

before:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (infos.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
echo %line%
```

After:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%G IN (infos.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
echo %line%
```

I just added delims=.

so now it shows me the whole Sentence and skips the first line.